# expected number of times to visit state j before hitting state i

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process

I have the following probability matrix:

\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0.75 & 0.25\\
0.75 & 0.25 & 0\\
1 & 0 &0
\end{pmatrix}

I want to calculate the expected number of times we visit state 3 before hitting state 2.

Now, I know that if I were looking at the probabilities I would use the following system:

\begin{cases} h_1= 0.75h_2 + 0.25h_3 \\ h_2=0 \\ h_3=1 \end{cases}

but I do not know how to translate this into the expected number of visits.

Comment: There was a recent question about a very similar problem...?

Comment: could you send me the link? I cannot find it

Comment: I cannot find it either, which is why I am confused.

Comment: Have you drawn a state transition diagram? This might help you see what's going on. Also, in which state do you start? State #1?

Comment: Yes, I have the diagram, but I still do not see it from there. The starting state indeed is 1

Comment: Let $X$ denote the number of trials until you hit state #2 given that you start at state #1. Can you find the pmf of $X$?

Comment: I am not sure if I understood you correctly, but the probability of hitting state 2 given I start in state 1 would be 1 right?

Comment: Yes; $P\Big(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\{X=n\}\Big)=1$. But what is, for example, the probability that you hit state #2 on the $7^{\text{th}}$ trial and not once before?

Comment: But how does this help me to find the expected number of visits to state 3?

Comment: so, is it 0.75^6*0.25 in case of hitting exactly on the 7th try

Comment: I'm getting $P(X=7)=(0.25)^3 \cdot (0.75)$

Comment: ohh ok, I saw what I was doing wrong

Comment: Notice that you can only reach state #2 for the first time after an odd number of trials which means that $X$ is supported on the set of positive odd integers $\{1,3,5,\ldots\}$. Can you try and find a formula for $P(X=2n+1)$ for $n=0,1,2,\ldots$? Moreover, if $V$ is the random variable which represents the number of times you visit state #3 before hiting state #2 for the first time, then $V=\frac{X-1}{2}$. Do you see this?

Comment: P(X=2n+1)= $(0.25)^n(0.75)$ , and yes, I see why V is that

Comment: Great. To find $E(X)$ all you have to do is evaluate the sum $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(2n+1)P(X=2n+1)$$ Now use linearity of expectation to find $E(V)$.

Comment: E(X=7)=3 and E(X=5)=2. So E((X-1)/2) is the expected value I am looking for right?

Comment: The expression $E(X=7)$ doesn't make any sense... Do you mean $E(V|X=7)=3$? Using linearity of expectation you can say $$E(V)=\frac{1}{2}\Big[E(X)-1\Big]$$ and you can compute $E(X)$ by evaluating the sum in my previous comment.

Comment: Yes, I meant E(V|X=7). Thanks a lot! I understand it know